# How to optimize django .get() with prefetch and select related?

Tags: django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I am currently experimenting with django to get a little bit more knowledgeable about queries and the orm. I am simply just doing trial and error on how to optimize them or even write them. Assuming my models are as follow,

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    isbn = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', related_name='books')

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ReadingList(models.Model):
    books = models.ManyToMany(Book, related_name='reading_lists')
```

I learned that I am able to optimize my query as follows

```
# example 1
query = Book.objects.all()  # or .filter(...)
query = query.only('name')
query = query.select_related('author')
query = query.prefetch_related('reading_lists')
```

this is definitely very useful especially with very long queries as it lets you easily break them up. However, when trying `.get()`, I end up getting errors: `'Book' object has no attribute 'only'`, `'Book' object has no attribute 'select_related'`, `'Book' object has no attribute 'prefetch_related'`

As it turns out, in order for me to use `.only()`, `.select_related()`, and `.prefetch_related()` is if I write them before the `.get()`

```
# example 2
Book.objects.only('name').select_related('author').prefetch_related('reading_lists').get(...)
```

Is there a way in which I can write `example 2` in the same way as `example 1`, just using `.get()`?

Comment: Yes, just use `item = query.get(...)` at the end of the chain. Querysets are lazy, so these will *not* be evaluated.

Comment: Follow up question. If I was to pass `Book.objects.get(..)` into a function, and i wanted to return the query with `.only()` or `.select_related()`, etc, is there no way to take the original `.get()` query and add the other parts after? Would there be a way to to do the other parts first and add the passed query after?

Comment: no, since `.get(..)` does not return a queryset: it makes a query and returns a model object, so then it is too late.

Answer (score 0):

`QuerySet`s are lazy, so you can keep chaining and end the call with a `.get(…)` that will then fetch the object:

```
query = Book.objects.all()
query = query.only('name')
query = query.select_related('author')
query = query.prefetch_related('reading_lists')
item = query.get(…)
```